# Finding a generating function from an expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Series representations:
$$
\frac{1}{2(1-x)^3}+\frac{1}{4(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{8(1-x)}+\frac{1}{8(1+x)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\left(7+(-1)^n+8n+2n^2\right).
$$

I'm trying to figure out to to turn this regular expression (to the left) to the generating function that WolframAlpha was so kind to provide it for me.

Or even just a way of finding the coefficient of a certain $x^n$ in the series...

By trying to simplify the expression I've got here :
$$
-\frac{1}{(x-1)^3(x+1)},
$$
I can break this down to 2 known series:
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = (1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-...)
$$
multiplied by:
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = (1-x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...)^3.
$$
But these are two series multiplied and I don't know how to continue from here to merge them both together to one series / generating function

I've been stuck on this for a couple of hours and I have no lead...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you know the series expansion of at least some parts of the LHS?

Comment: Each individually yes, but when I add them together things start to mess up

Comment: Thus, show how far you can go and THEN we will be able to help.

Comment: I've edited my original question, hope I made myself more clear now

Comment: Where are the series expansions of the parts of the LHS that you know how to expand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going in the opposite direction from the direction you want to be going.  Although $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^3}$ is more compact, the expression in your first equation, which is the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^3}$, is the more useful for getting the general term in the series.

The partial fraction decomposition is a sum of powers of binomials with constant coefficients.  What you want to do now is to use the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem) to express the binomial powers as series.  You already have the expansions of $(1-x)^{-1}$ and $(1+x)^{-1}$.  You also need the expansions of $(1-x)^{-2}$ and $(1-x)^{-3}$.  Combining the four terms with appropriate coefficients should give you the right hand side.

Comment: This is where I'm stuck at, I know the series of (1-x)^(-2) and (1-x)^(-3) how do I combine them to this sum exactly ?

Comment: You want $\frac{1}{2}$ times the $n^\text{th}$ term in the expansion of $(1-x)^{-3}$ plus $\frac{1}{4}$ times the $n^\text{th}$ term in the expansion of $(1-x)^{-2}$ plus $\frac{1}{8}$ times the $n^\text{th}$ term in the expansion of $(1-x)^{-1}$ plus $\frac{1}{8}$ times the $n^\text{th}$ term in the expansion of $(1+x)^{-1}$.